# 質問方法の確認時に出てくる「ありがとうございました」に違和感があります。

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

質問するボタンを押した後、「プライベート ベータでの質問方法」が表示され、最後に

ありがとうございました。質問をするときはこれらのヒントを参考にします。

の文言が表示されますが、日本人の感覚からいうと「ありがとうございました」よりも「了解しました」の方が自然かなと思いました。

（ベータ版しか表示されない画面なら修正不要ですが）